# How to show link to product in custom fields?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I'm a noobie and I have a question that's probably very simple to many people. I'm using Advanced Custom Fields, and WP Data Tables (https://wpdatatables.com/).

I made a custom post type "PC", and custom fields "CPU". "CPU"'s field type is Post Object, and it points to a Woocommerce product.

So when I make a table with WP Data Tables, I put the "CPU" custom field as one of the columns. But it just shows the post ID of the product, not the name or the link to the product. I want it to show the name of the custom field and link it to the Woocommerce product. How can I do that?

Thank you,
Andrew

Comment: Please elaborate your question and please share us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner and that's all I know about my problem.. On a table I want to show the name of the CPU product and have it linked to the product page. But when I tried to make a table, it just shows the post ID of the product.